# Process.Start() is not working on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, windows-server-2012

My Process.Start() implementation is not working in Windows 2012 R2

I deployed Windows Service on my Windows 2012 server. In the Windows Service I am tried to call one Batch (.bat) file using Process.Start(fileName).

When running service its not able to call the batch file.

I made the changes like NoInteractiveServices set to 0 and unblock all file .. but no luck..

anyone have different solution??

```
Private Function RunTask(ByVal sPath As String, ByVal sArgs As String, ByVal fLog As Boolean) As Boolean 
     Dim targetProcess As Process 

     Try 
          targetProcess = Process.Start(sPath, sArgs) 
     Catch ex As Exception 
          WriteToLog("Can not start process '" + sPath + "' - " + ex.Message) 
         Return False 
      End Try 

      If fLog = True Then 
         WriteToLog("Started process '" + sPath + "' with args '" + sArgs + "'") 
      End If 

      Return True 
 End Function
```

It calls the batch file and then continue code below code:

```
--> net stop "Exstream Monitor"
```

Answer (score 2):

> deployed windows service on windows 2012 server ... process.start(bat file name).

1. Does the service process have access rights to the file in question?
2. Are the properties of `CreateNoWindow` set to `true` and `UseShellExecute` set to `false`?
3. Is the service code capturing all exceptions and sending that information to a log or the system events?
4. The code avoids GUI popups or any/all GUI related tasks?
5. Can the bat file be run by hand and it works, or is it silently failing?

Comment: @harshalsuryavanshi and the service process has access rights to the directory/file in question?

Comment: yes. service account have full access on directory & c:\windows\temp directory.

Comment: 1. service account have full access on the file and folders 2. I tried to properties like CreateNoWindow & UseShellExecute 3. Service run properly but its not able to trigger bat file . and no error logged in event viewer . 4. This service not calling any GUI related code . It just calling bat file

Comment: what about running cmd.exe with an argument of /C batchfilename.bat

Comment: `bat` files can't be executed directly when `UseShellExecute` is false. You must invoke `cmd` instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. NoInteractiveServices set to 0
2. included service account in allow log on as batch, as service , allow remote access.
3. provided  full access to c:\windows\temp
4. provided full access rights to the directory/file

and rebooted the server and it solves the issue.